# checking if python object can be interpreted as real number [python]

Tags: python, real-number

I wrote the function in python:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        int(x) + 1
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

is there any difference if I write `float(x)` or `int(x)`? Or could `+ 1` part be useful in some case?

EDIT: `is_number_like` will return `True` when string is passed - that is what I don't want to be. I would like a function which will return `False` anytime a text-like value is passed as an argument. Is there a method for this?

maybe:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        x + 1
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

will be better?

or maybe:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        float(x + 1) == float(x) + 1
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

---

I want to write a module which would accept any well-behaved number type which represents one dimensional real number (for example `SimpleITK.sitkUInt8` number type or `numpy.int32` and so on...).

I'm afraid that there could be libraries, which will not throw an error in casting to int or float. For example I can imagine situation like this:

```
>>> z = SomeComplexType(1. + 2.j)
>>> z
(1+2j)
>>> z -= 2.j
>>> z
(1+0j)
>>> float(z) # does not raise an error
1.
```

is this possible, should I worry about such situation?

And do all well designed real number types will cast to `float` without an error?

*ps. i have read this already:
[How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)*

Comment: Have you tried what `int("1.23")` does? What is `x` supposed to be anyway? A string, or some other number-like object?

Comment: I get an error for `float((1+0j))` w/ both python 2.7 and 3.5 ("TypeError: can't convert complex to float")

Comment: x should be a list, an array (i want to return False then) or a numpy.int (which i want to make my function return True) and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're actually trying to do is find out whether an object behaves in "number"-like ways (e.g. can you append `+1` to it). If so, there's an easier way:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> 
>>> my_complex_number = 3-2j
>>> my_stringy_number = "3.14"
>>>
>>> isinstance(my_complex_number, Number)
True
>>> isinstance(my_stringy_number, Number)
False
```

Comment: Great! That works very well, but I have to exclude complex numbers.

Comment: Well you could also import `Real` from the `numbers` library, but note that `1.0+0j` would not be an instance of that.

Comment: if I use `numbers.Real` instead of `numbers.Number` - that solves my problem completely, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There **is a difference between `float(..)` and `int(..)`**.

`float(..)` will try to parse a **`str`ing** or any object that has a **`__float__` method**. For example **`int`, `float` and `complex` have a `__float__` method**. You can define such method for a custom class as well.

If you aim to convert a complex number to a `float(..)`, it will error:

```
>>> float(2+2j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

The **result of a `float(..)` function is guaranteed to be a `float`**: if the `__float__` method returns a non-float value, it will **raise a `TypeError`**:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __float__(self):
...         return 2j
... 
>>> float(Foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __float__ returned non-float (type complex)
```

So a simply `float(..)` try is sufficient:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except TypeError, ValueError:
        return False
```

Most *numeric-like* types in Python (like the `numpy.int16`) **support such `__float__` method.

**`int(..)` on the other hand works with a `str`ing and with the `__int__` method**. Again if you call **`int(..)`, the result is guaranteed to be an `int`**.

So in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you could use two checks: one for `float(..)` and one for `int(..)`:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except TypeError, ValueError:
        try:
            float(x)
            return True
        except TypeError, ValueError:
            return False
```

Or if you want to return the number-like object:

```
def is_number_like(x):
     try:
        return int(x)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            return float(x)
        except TypeError:
            return None
```

(this will return `None` if both attempts fail).

Mind that in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), there is also a `long` type (and guess what, it works with `__long__`).

Comment: shouldn't you first try to cast to `int` and then `float`? Nothing will be `int` the way it is now.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: I do not really get your comment. Can you please reformulate?

Comment: If you pass "1" in your `is_number_like()` function it will create a `float`, not an `int`. In my opinion, the outer `try` block should be like `int(x)` and if that fails try `float(x)`. For this example it does not make any difference because it only returns `True` \ `False` but generally speaking..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: no, it will return `True`. This is a *check* wether it *is* number-like, not converting it to a *number-like* object. But you are correct that if you want to convert it, you can try `int` first. Will alter the answer.

Comment: I noticed the return value later, sorry. But you get my point.

Comment: Also `float(1+0j)` raises a `TypeError` for me. What Python version are you running?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: hmm. Somehow I tested this. But now I cannot reproduce this. Modified. Thanks for your remarks :).

Answer (score 1):

In python complex numbers can't be directly converted to int nor float this would raise a `TypeError: can't convert complex to...`.

Any other object than an "int or float convertible" one will raise a  `ValueError`.

To make an object from a custom class "convertible" one will have to define the appropriate "dunders" `__int__` and `__float__`, [see doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

So a function that check if a object can be cast as a real number you can do this:

```
def is_real_number(number):
    try:
        int(number)
    except TypeError, ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: ok, that is clarifying - and what about string? is the other method i wrote better for excluding strings? (see edit in my post)

Comment: If the string only contains a number it will be cast otherwise it will also raise a ValueError

Comment: but i don't want it to cast any string to number. any advice how to make it universal working?

Comment: Check if the given object is an instance of string with the [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) builtin. (This will work also for string subclass)

Comment: Actually @Marc gave the best answer if you only want to check if the object is a number is the [numbers.Number](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number) class

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
any([isinstance(x, t) for t in [float, int, complex]])
```

You can modify the list of types to be whatever you need it to be.

Comment: There are a lot of *number-like* objects like `numpy.int16` that are not an `int`, but *can be converted into an `int`*.

Comment: i want to use any types the user can invent, for example numpy.float64. i cant enumerate all of them

Comment: @Śmigło: indeed, since you can define types in your own program that are *number-like*.